# close (Chrome) browser window on navbar click

Tags: r, shiny

I have been using the approach [suggested by @wch on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24646283/1974918) to close the browser window when clicking an action button in a Shiny app. Works great.

I would now like to stop my app *and* close the bowser window (in Chrome) when clicking an element in the navbar. Below the tabPanel call I'm using

```
tabPanel(title = "", value = "Stop", icon = icon("power-off"))
```

I use an observer to stop the app when the value of `input$navbar == "Stop"` (i.e, when the icon in the navbar is selected) but I'm not sure how to activate the `window.close()` call.

Code for action button to close browser windows by @wch

```
tags$button(
  id = 'close',
  type = "button",
  class = "btn action-button",
  onclick = "window.close();",
  "Close window"
)
```

EDIT:

Found a work-around that does what I want.

```
tabPanel(tags$a(id = "quitApp", href = "#", class = "action-button",
         list(icon("power-off"), ""), onclick = "window.close();"))
```

Unfortunately it leads to a rather badly aligned navbar. I asked a [related question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/R88VpjRRu_U) on the Shiny google group

[image: badly aligned navbar]

Comment: could you provide a bit more code to have a fully reproducible shiny app please

Comment: anything wrong/insufficient with the answer I provided?

Comment: @daattali I like the answer so I up-voted it. However, I would prefer an option that doesn't require a package dependency. That may not be feasible however.

Comment: Sure, you can get away without the package dependency - are you familiar with "session$sendCustomMessage" to call javascript functions? I only used this package because it makes calling JS functions easier and less messy, but you can replicate my solution with sendCustomMessage if you know how to use it

Comment: @daattali I haven't used sendCustomMessage much. I would happily give you the 'check' for that answer however.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [shinyjs](https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs) package to easily call javascript functions, which is essentially all you need to do.  Disclaimer: I wrote that package. Here's the code to do what you want:

```
library(shinyjs)
jscode <- "shinyjs.closewindow = function() { window.close(); }"

runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = tagList(
    useShinyjs(),
    extendShinyjs(text = jscode),
    navbarPage(
      "test",
      id = "navbar",
      tabPanel(title = "tab1"),
      tabPanel(title = "", value = "Stop", icon = icon("power-off"))
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observe({
      if (input$navbar == "Stop") {
        js$closewindow();
        stopApp()
      }
    })
  }
))
```

**EDIT**:

If you don't want to use a JS package, you can do the same thing with native shiny:

```
jscode <- "Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('closeWindow', function(m) {window.close();});"

runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = tagList(
    tags$head(tags$script(HTML(jscode))),
    navbarPage(
      "test",
      id = "navbar",
      tabPanel(title = "tab1"),
      tabPanel(title = "", value = "Stop", icon = icon("power-off"))
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observe({
      if (input$navbar == "Stop") {
        session$sendCustomMessage(type = "closeWindow", message = "message")
        stopApp()
      }
    })
  }
))
```

Comment: Nice suggestion @daattali. I will try that out.